# getting user list from slack API using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, api, slack, slack-api

I am creating a slack bot and am trying to get the list of members in a slack workspace. Below is my code.

```
getUserList() {
    axios.get(`https://slack.com/api/users.list?token=`+process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN).then((res) => {      
      var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(res);
      for (i = 0; i < jsonParsed; i++) {
        workspace_users.push(jsonParsed[i].name); 
      }
    });
  },
```

I am getting below response.

```
{"ok":true,"no_op":true,"already_open":true,"channel":{"id":"*****"},"scopes":["identify","bot:basic"],"acceptedScopes":["im:write","post"]}
```

I went to https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list and I am not getting the kind of result mention in the URL.

I have already given the scope permission to my bot.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this looks like a weird response from the API. are you maybe using a workspace token?

Comment: I am using "Bot User OAuth Access Token" from OAuth & Permissions tab

Comment: I am getting the user list now after modifying the request url to "`https://${process.env.SLACK_ENV}.slack.com/api/users.list?token=`+process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN)". I am trying to parse it "JSON.parse(res.data.members)" but it is saying member is undefind

Comment: your URL is not correct. it is always: `https://slack.com/api/users.list`. If it does not work with that URL, there must be another issue

Comment: Its working with same url. I completed my task. thanks for replying.